Snowflake SQL code to extract 2 values from string
I have a field with a long string and need to extract 2 values into 2 new columns
need to get pages as one column and price as second column
example field: need the number value for pages after annual fee to be one column and then the dollar amount after pages to be the second new column
"The xyz Company
Effective 24-Jan-2024
24 Month Term

Annual Fee bills in Quarterly Installments $xxx,x00.00
Year 1:
Annual Fee Up to x0,000,000 pages @ $x,xx0,000.00"

regexp_like(special_terms, 'Annual Fee') tried to get pages but did not work

You have "annual fee" twice in the sample data. Is that always the case? Is that sample data just one sample row? It's not well formatted.

You could use nested split_part; however, your data must be consistent. If your data are messy then your solution will be messy. Best to fix the upstream system which feeds the database and then modify your database table.
with my_data as (
 select 'The xyz Company Effective 24-Jan-2024 24 Month Term Annual Fee bills in Quarterly Installments $xxx,x00.00 Year 1: Annual Fee Up to x0,000,000 pages @ $x,xx0,000.00'  as col1 union all 
 select 'Annual Fee Up to 10,500 pages @ $4,000'
)
select 
  split_part(split_part(col1, 'Annual Fee Up to ', 2),' pages @ ', 1) as pages, 
  split_part(split_part(col1, 'Annual Fee Up to ', 2),' pages @ ', 2) as price
from my_data




PAGES
PRICE




x0,000,000
$x,xx0,000.00


10,500
$4,000



Also, I didn't put this in the query because I don't know why you have 'x' in your sample data, but should also cast those two columns as the appropriate type.
